# What is the distinction between positivism and logical positivism?

Tags: logical-positivism, positivism

I've heard that positivism aimed to be purely empirical, while logical positivism recognised that empiricism needed to be combined with logic in order to actually be able to figure out anything. Is this an accurate characterisation of these two movement?

Comment: Can you place these terms in context? Positivism is a term that has been used in multiple ways (see for instance http://www.iep.utm.edu/durkheim/ )

Comment: @virmaior: What distinguished logical positivism (that developed in the Vienna circle) from earlier forms?

Comment: Positivism was mainly 19th Century: [Auguste Comte](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/comte/).

Comment: [Logical Empiricism (or Positivism)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-empiricism/) developed in Europe in 1930s and in US in the 40s.

Comment: The key-words is "logical": the new "version" developed under the influence of Russell and Wittgenstein.

Comment: "What held the group together was a common concern for scientific methodology and the important role that science could play in reshaping society. Within that scientific methodology the logical empiricists wanted to find a natural and important role for logic and mathematics and to find an understanding of philosophy according to which it was part of the scientific enterprise."

Comment: Auguste Comte should be the positivist.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not.

The basic ideal of positivism, both old and new, was to purify science by eliminating from it all speculation (the positivists identified all speculation with "metaphysics", in a derogatory sense). The older kind of positivism was just more humble. It was a philosophy of science. A typical project of the old positivism was Ernst Mach's attempt to rewrite Newton's physics [without assuming absolute space](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#8). With logical positivism, the stakes got raised. It was emboldened by new developments in the foundations of logic, and mathematics, which seemed to promise new and scientific foundations for language generally. And with [verifiability as a criterion of meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verificationism), not just of good science, logical positivism posited itself as a basic philosophy, not just as a philosophy of science. The logical positivists were indeed occupied with logic, that is inductive logic, the logic of discovery, empirical verification and probability.